# Draw 3D points and export their coordinate

Tags: matlab, 3d, coordinates

My matlab function gets some 3D point coordinate (max 30) as input. (nx3 matrix)
I want to specify the points in a user friendly **3D graphical environment** and then export their coordination.
Can you show me a standard and simple way to do that?

Comment: How?, Using interactive graphical pick (like ginput function)?, or using a user interface (uitable or edit text) to input data manually?

Comment: @JorgeDeLosSantos Interactive graphical pick I mean. like ginput function but in 3d mode. It can be outside matlab and write list of (x,y,z) in a file.